# Doubt about uniqueness of limit proof

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-explanation

My lecturer gave us a proof of uniqueness of limit by contradiction, the context is: let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set, let $x_0$ be a limit point for $X$ and let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. If the limit of $f$ exists then it must be unique.

I have a doubt in the proof, which is the following: suppose by the sake of contradiction that $f$ has two limits $y_1 \ne y_2$ as $x \to x_0$. Let $V_1$ be a neighbourhood of $y_1$ and $V_2$ be a neighbourhood of $y_2$, with $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$. Since $x_0$ is a limit point, we can find two neighbourhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of the point $x_0$ such that for all $x \in U_1 \cap X \setminus \{x_0\}$ it is $f(x) \in V_1$ and for all $x \in U_2 \cap X \setminus \{x_0\}$ it is $f(x) \in V_2$. Since $U-1$ and $U_2$ are neighbourhoods of $x_0$ it is $U_1 \cap U_2 \ne \emptyset$ and since $x_0$ is a limit point there exists at least a point $\bar{x} \in X$ such that $\bar{x} \in U_1 \cap U_2$. So if $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$ it is $f(x) \in V_1$ and $f(x) \in V_2$, meaning $V_1 \cap V_2 \ne \emptyset$ and this contradicts the fact that $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$.

My doubt is: *what if $V_1$ and $V_2$ aren't disjoint*? I will try to explain my doubt: proofs must be general, and it seems to me that when he says "let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be such that $V_1 \cap V_2 =\emptyset$" we are restricting to a case that it isn't general because it imposes a condition on $V_1$ and $V_2$, that is that they are disjoint. Why this proof works then? I have a suspect that it is because this restriction is "apparent", in the sense that we can *always* lead back to the case when $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint (for example, if $V_1$ and $V_2$ aren't disjoint I can consider another neighbourhoods $V_1'$ and $V_2'$ with radius, for example, a fraction the radius of $V_1$ and $V_2$ big enough to assure that $V_1'$ and $V_2'$ are disjoint), and so obtain a general proof because the condition we impose can always be imposed and this makes $V_1 \cap V_2 =\emptyset$ an assumption without loss of generality. This has some sense or am I missing the point? Thanks.

Comment: Yes: if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are distinct real numbers, they **do** have disjoint nbhds, and therefore we can always choose our nbhds of $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be disjoint. (E.g., let $\epsilon=\frac12|y_1-y_2|$, and let $V_i=(y_i-\epsilon,y_i+\epsilon)$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are misunderstanding the meaning of the idea that proofs must be general. We are assuming that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are limits of $f$ at $x_0$. Asserting that $y_1$ is limit of $f$ at $x_0$ means that for *every* neighborhood $V_1$ of $y_1$, there is a neighborhood $U_1$ of $x_0$ such that $x\in U_1\implies f(x)\in V_1$. And asserting that $y_2$ is limit of $f$ at $x_0$ means that for *every* neighborhood $V_2$ of $y_2$, there is a neighborhood $U_2$ of $x_0$ such that $x\in U_2\implies f(x)\in V_2$. Since this is true for *every* two neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively, then, in particular, it must still be true when we choose those neighborhoods in such a way that they don't intersect. And doing that leads to a contradiction.

A proof being general means that it has to apply to every single case. But, in this context, this does *not* mean that it must work if we pick *any* two neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$. If one pair of such neighborhoods leads to a contradiction, that's fine and we have then a proof.